# Can a remote user run a Psexec batch file that remotely prompts a designated domain admin to enter their credential to authorize the request?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, psexec

Is it possible for Psexec or any other method that will remotely prompt a designated admin to enter their credentials?

The remote user on the domain or domain VPN would have the file.  If they need to run it, they don't have admin access.  Looking for a way to script the file to have the user enter my domain username that will prompt me to enter my admin credential to allow the script to run with admin privileges.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In one word: no. And why would any sane administrator enter their credentials to authorize someone else running elevated commands, just because they're prompted to do so?

What you can do is create a scheduled task running under an administrative account that your users can trigger manually.